# Laravel Field 'status' doesn't have a default value, I've tried answers in related posts to no avail

Tags: php, laravel

I've used the auth command to get the default login and registering pages, and i've modified them to fit the fields in my database. but when i try to register i get the error:

"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'status' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ("name", "email", "encrypted password", date, date)) "

I have tried setting it to have a default on the migration create table, but the problem still persists:

```
$table->string('status')->default('unapproved');
```

This is my register controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

my migration table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('status')->default('unapproved');
            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(true);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

And my user model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'status',
        'is_active',

    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Like i mentioned before, having set the default i should be able to insert the user into the table, but i get that "Field 'status' doesn't have a default value" error, which i assume would happen to is_active too, but it fails before it gets to it

Comment: Was this migration run before you changed the default to `unapproved`?

Comment: ^ You understand the error? Remove Laravel from equation, I'd assume the table definition is NOT NULL for the field `status` and since your insert does not provide a value, and the definition has no default, the insert fails. what does `desc youTableName` tell you? Run migration larval thingy...

Comment: I dropped all the tables and remigrated them, and that seems to have solved it, thanks!